# Implementing scrollable horizontal menu

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I am new to iOS and trying to implement something exactly like the scrollable bar with the various sports show [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwzob.png).

I want the user to be able to scroll horizontally through the various options and be able to select one. It can be very simple like the one linked, as long as it is clear what is selected.

I'm not sure where exactly to start. Should I be using a CollectionView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right - UICollectionView is the best option for you. Do set the collectionView's layout to UICollectionViewFlowLayout with horizontal direction.

Setup the UIViewController to be the collectionView's data source and delegate. The selection with tapping will be available immediately provided by default UICollectionView behaviour. The collectionView's delegate will allow you to intercept the event when collection is scrolled to new item so you would be able to determine the new selected item.